# Keep track of password in Ubuntu

Tags: password

Is there a keychain-like program included with Ubuntu? Or is there something I can sudo apt-get ? I really liked dashlane on osx. What's the best software available that can keep track of passwords for websites, and also hold important information regarding logins? ssh addresses, things like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See dash, password and keys.

[image]

The program is called [seahorse](https://projects.gnome.org/seahorse/) and is already installed and active on your system.

```
Seahorse - Encryption Made Easy
Seahorse is a GNOME application for managing encryption keys. 
It also integrates with nautilus, gedit and other places for encryption operations. 

With seahorse you can...
Create and manage PGP keys
Create and manage SSH keys
Publish and retrieve keys from key servers
Cache your passphrase so you don't have to keep typing it
Backup your keys and keyring
more...
```

Press the super key to go to dash and start typing `password` and it will be the 1st result.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 'Revelation', which is available from the Softwarecenter. A very usefull program, very good integration in gnome. Archive will be encrypted. Information is stored in folders, entries can be defined as Website, Email, etc.